# Trouble with AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a form, and it has a field for entering a PIN code. Here I am using ajax for finding place when enter PIN code. It works when that field is not enclose in a form. If it is enclosed in a form, AJAX is not working.

**HTML CODE:**

```
<form id="form" class="blocks" action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="col_4 right">
        <label for="fullname">FirstName:</label>
        <input name="fname" type="text" class="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="col_4 right">
        <label for="pincode">Pin-Code:</label>
        <input name="pincode" type="text" class="text" id="pincode"  />
        <div id="section1"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JS CODE:**

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
             $('#pincode').keyup(function (e) {
                 if (e.keyCode == 13) {


                    //ajax request
                    $.ajax({
                         url: "pincode_check.php",
                        data: {
                            'pincode' : $('#pincode').val()
                        },
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data) { <!--console.log(data.success);-->
                            if(data.success){
                                //console.log(data.results[0].formatted_address.split(','))
                                var long_address=data.results[0].formatted_address.split(',');
                                console.log(long_address[0]);
                                $('#section1').append(long_address[0]);

                            }
                        }
                    });
                 }
                });

           });


        </script>
```

**PHP CODE(pincode_check.php):**

```
<?php 
    $pincode=$_REQUEST['pincode'];
    $geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$pincode.'&sensor=false');
    $response= json_decode($geocode); //Store values in variable
    $lat = $response->results[0]->geometry->location->lat; //Returns Latitude
    $long = $response->results[0]->geometry->location->lng; // Returns Longitude
    $geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$lat.','.$long.'&sensor=false');
    $data= json_decode($geocode);

    if($data==true)
    { // Check if address is available or not
        $data->results[0]->formatted_address ;   
        $data->success=true;
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
    else {
        $data->success= false;

        echo json_encode($data);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working". What is happening? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Is the control entering the ajax  code ? if yes then,add a error section for ajax call to see if its returning any error message from server end

Comment: in form feild enctype="multipart/form-data" is set.then ajax not work.i remove it from form then it work.

Comment: Your code is working for me.

Comment: no..when this feild is inside the form code is not working

Comment: Is it not calling the ajax function or the response not coming from the php file?

Comment: pincode input feils is inside the form feild tag.ajax  not working sir

Comment: Your code is working properly. Here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3QEdE/

Answer (score 0):

The default content type in `$.ajax` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. But you've set your form content to `multipart/form-data`.

`multipart/form-data` is normally used for sending files with POST. I don't think you need that, so you don't need to specify `enctype` at all, just remove it and use the default form encoding, which is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

(Additionally, the default request type in `$.ajax` is GET, so if you do want to send a file, you'll need to change that too..as well as add the attribute `type="file"` to your form I believe...)